# What does "a bean" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang

Here is a comic with "a bean" written on the head of the ENFP character. What does it mean?

[image: A bean]

[Image Description: A two-panel comic drawn in a quickly sketched style. The first panel shows a character labeled INTJ saying "I am some kind of non-human being. I do not have emotions." The second panel shows a second character entering the frame. They are labeled ENFP and have a second label describing them as "A bean." They are smiling and holding their hands to their cheeks in a pose intended to look cute. They are saying "Are you sure?" The INTJ character is shown sweating and looking away.]

Comment: Please transcribe **all** the words in the image as text in your question. People with screen readers can't read the text in the image, and people searching for words in your image won't find this question.

Comment: @gotube It won't show up until it has been peer-reviewed, but I edited the post and added a full image description with transcription.

Comment: @FriendlyRacoon Great work. Better than just a transcription.

Comment: What are INTJ and ENFP?  Political parties in some country?  Is this a political cartoon? If so perhaps BEAN is a local term, and might not even be English.

Comment: Personality types. https://eu.themyersbriggs.com/en/tools/MBTI/MBTI-personality-Types/ENFP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Bean" or "smol (small) bean" is recent-ish (ca. 2015) youth slang for a sweet and innocent character. It fell out of favor when it came to be associated with infantilization of real celebrities and flawed characters.

"Cinnamon roll" is an equivalent term of similar vintage without quite so many problematic connotations. The counterparts to these terms in 2023 ("meowmeow" and "babygirl") come with a distinctly ironic flavor.

As always, it's inadvisable for non-natives to try to use slang unless you become intimately familiar with how it's used, and no one over 30 would really use these particular terms at all.

Comment: Have you got proof that it fell out of favor for that reason?

Comment: I've never heard any of these terms used with these meanings. You say "no one over 30 would really use these" and I am well over 30, so maybe that's not surprising. But it brings up an issue that I've found necessary to bring up on this site many times: Be careful when using words or phrases that have a very localized meaning. This applies to technical terms, like "force" means something very different to a physicist than it does to a military man. It applies doubly to slang, which not only can be very specific to one age group or region, but also often comes and goes very rapidly. ...

Comment: ...  It's easy to fall into the trap of thinking, "Everyone I know uses this word to mean this, so it is a commonly used and understood word", when in fact "everyone you know" is a very small niche group.

Comment: @Jay for context, these are younger-millennial and Gen Z terms popularized on social media sites like Tumblr and Archive of Our Own (arguably not a social media site, but close enough). They are most popular in fandom spaces. Here's the urban dictionary link: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=smol%20bean

Comment: I've just looked up the two sets of initials, and it appears that INTJ stands for 'Introverted, intuitive, thinking and judging' and ENFP 'Extroverted, intuitive, feeling and perceiving' - two personality types.